# int128 or 16 byte integers in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to declare intgers of type unsigned `int128` in postgresI need to be able to ingest/represent 16 byte integers.

I saw that there is [a .h file](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/common/int128.h) for it but haven't seen any implementation examples

Answer (score 2):

You can store 128-bit integers using the DECIMAL type.

For example:

```
create table t (p int , value decimal(39),
  check (value between -170141183460469231731687303715884105728::decimal(39)
                   and  170141183460469231731687303715884105727::decimal(39))
  );
```

Result:

```
    p                                     value  
 ----- ----------------------------------------- 
   15                                     32768  
   16                                     65536  
   31                                2147483648  
   32                                4294967296  
   63                       9223372036854775808  
   64                      18446744073709551616  
  127   170141183460469231731687303715884105727
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fQX8ZQ1y).

Notice the last insert fails since the value exceeds the 128-bit precision by one unit.